# Can I install MABS in a server which is node in a wsfc cluster which I'm using for Availability group? If not then why?

Tags: azure, backup, disaster-recovery, azure-backup-vault, availability-group

In MABS documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-microsoft-azure-backup) It's written that we can't install MABS on a computer which is node of a cluster so I just wanted to make sure that I'll need additional machine for that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an additional machine would be required.